# How to construct a context free grammar $G$ such that $L(G) = \{ a^i b^j a^k| j \gt i+k\} $?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

How to construct a context free grammar $G$ such that $L(G) = \{ a^i b^j a^k| j \gt i+k\} $?

**My attempt:**

$G_1 = (\{ S,A,B\}, \{a,b\},P,S)$ where $P$ consists of:
$$ S\to AbBC $$
$$A \to aAb|\lambda$$ $$  B \to bB|\lambda $$ $$ C \to bCa|\lambda$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This has been flagged as off-topic. Is there a better place for it?

Comment: @robjohn I think http://cs.stackexchange.com/ would be a much better fit.

Comment: @haunted85 The same user asked (almost) the same question on [cs.SE] earlier this day and deleted it again. Not clear whether the reason was self-vandalism, sulkiness or something else entirely.

Comment: @haunted85: We routinely answer such questions.

Comment: This is a special case of [this recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/371283/12042); the accepted answer there, combined with Arthur Fischer’s answer, should help.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  Can obvious special cases be considered 'duplicates'?  I would be in favour of closing this as a duplicate, but I'm not quite sure whether that is a generally accepted position.

Comment: @Tara: My rule on voting to close is *when in doubt, don’t*. That said, I thought seriously about it for this question and probably would have voted to close if the answer to the other question had been complete, rather than a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings your grammar generate are of the form $\mathtt{a}^i \mathtt{b}^{j} \mathtt{a}^k \mathtt{b}^k$ (or $\mathtt{0}^i \mathtt{1}^{j} \mathtt{0}^k \mathtt{1}^k$ with notational changes) where $j > i$.  (You're use of the non-terminal $A$ in two spots in the starting rule made you go awry as the order of the $\mathtt{a}$s and $\mathtt{b}$s (or $\mathtt{0}$s and $\mathtt{1}$s) matters.)

Don't be afraid to use more non-terminal symbols! (well, one more.)